# Удостоить (чего?) или (чем?)

Tags: грамотная-речь, склонение, падежи

Спорим с заказчиком о правильности: "Он [лимонарий] удостоен дипломов и грамот" или же "Он удостоен дипломами и грамотами"?
И в другом случае: "Она удостоила его презрительного взгляда/презрительным взглядом"? И есть ли разница в зависимости от контекста?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Правильно:

(1) Он [лимонарий] удостоен **дипломов и грамот (Р. п.).**

(2) Она удостоила его **презрительным (ласковым) взглядом (Т. п.).**

Примечание:  удостоить ласкового взгляда (Р. п., **устар.**)

**Из словаря: УДОСТОИТЬ,  св.**

**1. Наградить, признать достойным (высок., Р. п.)** кого-что чего. Высок. Признав достойным, наградить чем-л., присвоить какое-л. звание, степень и т.п.  У. Нобелевской премии кого-л. **Работа удостоена почётного диплома.**

**2. Оказать внимание (ирон.,  Т. п.)** кого-что (чего) и **чем. (ирон.).** Оказать кому-, чему-л. какое-л. внимание, расположение, участие и т. п., относясь при этом к нему с некоторым снисхождением, высокомерием, пренебрежением и т. п. **У. одобрительным взглядом.**

Answer (score 4):

Да, контекст имеет значение. Различие в том, что стоящие за этим близкие по смыслу и различные по форме полные грамматические конструкции упрощаются до слова "удостоить" по-разному. В одном случае подчёркивается *достоинство*, в другом - связанное с ним *действие*. Это различие настолько существенно, что в толковых словарях рассматриваются два раздельных значения самого слова, свойственные разным контекстам.

1. [наградить, признав достойным] **чего-либо**
2. [счесть достойным своего внимания, "наградив (одарив)"] **чем-либо**

Comment: Благодарю. Т. е. моя версия с "удостоен дипломов и грамот" и "удостоила презрительным взглядом" верна, я правильно расцениваю этот самый контекст?

Comment: Думаю, что правильно.